# Problema IIS con ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis

Buenas les dejo los errores que visualizo en el visor de eventos:

Error 1

```
Exception : The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
```

Error 2

```
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT

Process ID: 6972

Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

StackTrace:    at System.Collections.ArrayList.Add(Object value)
   at log4net.Util.LogReceivedEventHandler.Invoke(Object source, LogReceivedEventArgs e)
   at log4net.Util.LogLog.OnLogReceived(Type source, String prefix, String message, Exception exception)
   at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.Finalize()
```

Error 3

```
An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe [6972]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: Debugger could not be started because no user is logged on.

Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' for more information.
```

Appenders log4net:

```
 <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" 
        type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

      <file value="backend-end-log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />

      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <acceptOnMatch value="true" />

        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
      <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
      </layout>

    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>

  </log4net>
```

Falla la app y me devuelve estos errores.

Desde ya gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException , Significa que te estas saliendo de rango en una iteracion

Comment: Si al parecer es algo con log4net pero realmente no encuentro el problema

Comment: consulta, estas accediendo a la aplicación desde el mismo servidor o desde otro equipo? con que explorador accedes a la aplicación?

Comment: Puede mostrar la configuarcion para los appenders de log4net?

Comment: te explico la estructura del proyecto para que sea mas facil. El proyecto tiene un backend que se divide en una app web y un servicio .svc. El backend esta en 3 servidores con un balanceador para distribuir la carga. tmb esta el frontend que usa al .svc para comunicarse con backend y base de datos y ademas de esto un servicio de windows que ejecuta metodos de el mismo .svc ahi es donde tengo problemas cuando el servicio de windows trata de comunicarse con el balanceador falla por alguna razon y tira esos errores.

Comment: Te lo agrego al post @Duston

Comment: Ante un error de una librería o componente externo, lo mejor es que elimines las referencias y posteriormente las vuelvas a agregar, es posible que algo por ahí se haya corrompido, la solución más rápida y sana sería esa, además que por tratarse de algo que realmente no desarrollaste tú te meterías en líos